# How to make a logs using log4j having a custom header?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am making a log file using log4j having the following format:
x,x,x,x
x,x
x,x,x
x
Num
Num
Num
Num
.
.
.

To put the headers i.e the first 4 lines containing those x, I have  extended the PatternLayout class and overridden the getHeader() method.
getHeader code is as follows:

```
@Override
public String getHeader(){
    return FIRST_LINE + SECOND_LINE + THIRD_LINE + FOURTH_LINE;
}
```

I am hosting my app on weblogic server.
The issue is that whenever I restart the server,the headers get appended every time.
And the other issue is that when I hit the first request after restarting, the headers get appended again like:

"Header after restart"
"Header after first request"

Could anyone please suggest how can I solve this issue or any other alternative to make the same report with 4 header lines and other dynamic values after those headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this problem.
We will override the getHeader() method and will return the header only when it is needed.
I have used the following approach:

1. Check whether first line of the log file is empty or not.
2. If the first line is not there in the log file, only then I will return the headers from getHeader() method.

You can use the following code to solve this issue:

```
 @Override
public String getHeader () {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (fileName)) {

        String line = br.readLine ();
        if (line != null)
            return null;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }

    return FIRST_LINE + SECOND_LINE + THIRD_LINE + FOURTH_LINE;
}
```

Note that this code will only check the first line of the file and not the complete file.